# value must be a number less than infinity

Tags: c#

I have the following line of code in my app:

```
packsize.CompanyPrice = (decimal)Reader["CompanyPrice"];
```

but it raises an error `when casting from a number, the value must be a number less than infinity`

i have set database datatype as double, but in my app it is decimal. Does it cause this problem?

or  I am missing something here ??

Comment: Well, what is the incoming value of `CompanyPrice`? Note that `decimal` has a max value of 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335 (which is, to be fair, pretty huge... depending on which currency you are using)

Comment: What is the content of `Reader["CompanyPrice"]` before casting to `decimal`?

Comment: Have a condition to check for the value before assigning it. Some valid condition

Comment: @SKPaul I'm not convinced the current value is 0. What happens if you just look at `object o = Reader["CompanyPrice"];` ? what is `o.GetType()` ? what is `o.ToString()` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to cast a DBNull Value hence you are getting the error

Good if you can add a check for `Reader["CompanyPrice"]` for `DBNull`

```
if(Reader["CompanyPrice"] != DBNull.Value)
{
}
```

something like this can reproduce your issue

```
object obj = DBNull.Value;
decimal somdec = (decimal)obj; // Specified cast is not valid
```

**EDIT**

If its a boxed representation of a double then you will need to cast it back to a double and then do the cast to decimal.

Comment: i have set database datatype as double, but in my app it is decimal. Does it cause this problem?

Comment: yeah it could be issue if it has been double -> object so when you get back you will need to get the double and then the decimal, this is best [explained here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Reader["CompanyPrice"]   returns a value is infinity or NaN I am guessing. Set it to int.MaxValue or decimal.MaxValue

Comment: i have set database datatype as double, but in my app it is decimal. Does it cause this problem?

Comment: If the data is from the database, use double.TryParse. Don't directly cast from a string to a decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Try clamping value of Reader["CompanyPrice"] before casting (decimal)
for 32-bit int the minimum is -2147483648 and the maximum is 2147483647

Comment: decimal has a max of 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335... `decimal`  is not `Int32`