# How to avoid this kind of exception?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I have an sqlite database, and a table, in which i have a column PIN as a TEXT, and it's empty.
when i'm getting it from the database, and trying to convert into a string it brings me an exception, When casting a number the value must be less then infinity...what is the reason?

Comment: Which exception exactly? Also please include some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In databases like sqlite, empty strings and null are two different things.  It looks like you may be trying to cast your PIN to an `int`, or some other integer type.  If the PIN field is null or DBNull, this cast will fail, giving the exception you listed.  To further complicate things, `null != DBNull.Value`, which is what your database query is likely returning.

To check for this, you need to check the PIN field against `DBNull.Value` and cast only after you've checked.

See: [DBNull Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

See: [A similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932489/value-must-be-a-number-less-than-infinity)